# App loaded in Django admin, but doesn't showing up

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to add my app to django admin panel. I have 3 apps:

1. users
2. orders
3. advertisements

All this applications loaded in settings.INSTALLED_APPS correctly, but django-admin showing up only two apps: users and orders. The most interesting in this situation is that in source code of html file for django-admin panel all apps are loaded, but app advertisements
doesn't showing up. As you can see below, code for advertisements app is loaded in html file. When I try to go on links for this app in **a** tags, i see only white screen on opened page, but source code for page is loaded too. Thanks a lot for any help.

```
<div id="content-main">
  
    <div class="app-advertisements module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/advertisements/" class="section" title="Models in the Advertisements application">Advertisements</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-advertisingspacecategory">
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/advertisements/advertisingspacecategory/">Advertising space categorys</a></th>
              <td><a href="/admin/advertisements/advertisingspacecategory/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/advertisements/advertisingspacecategory/" class="changelink">Change</a></td>
              
          </tr>
        
          <tr class="model-advertisingspace">
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/advertisements/advertisingspace/">Advertising spaces</a></th>
              <td><a href="/admin/advertisements/advertisingspace/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/advertisements/advertisingspace/" class="changelink">Change</a></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="app-auth module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/auth/" class="section" title="Models in the Authentication and Authorization application">Authentication and Authorization</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-group">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/auth/group/">Groups</a></th>
              <td><a href="/admin/auth/group/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/auth/group/" class="changelink">Change</a></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="app-orders module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/orders/" class="section" title="Models in the Orders application">Orders</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-order">
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/orders/order/">Orders</a></th>
              <td><a href="/admin/orders/order/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/orders/order/" class="changelink">Change</a></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="app-users module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/users/" class="section" title="Models in the Users application">Users</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tr class="model-user">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/users/user/">Users</a></th>
              <td><a href="/admin/users/user/add/" class="addlink">Add</a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/users/user/" class="changelink">Change</a></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Code in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
"django.contrib.admin",
"django.contrib.auth",
"django.contrib.contenttypes",
"django.contrib.sessions",
"django.contrib.messages",
"django.contrib.staticfiles",
"phonenumber_field",
"users.apps.UsersConfig",
"orders.apps.OrdersConfig",
"advertisements.apps.AdvertisementsConfig",
]
```

Code in admin.py for advertisements app

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import AdvertisingSpace, AdvertisingSpaceCategory

admin.site.register(AdvertisingSpace)
admin.site.register(AdvertisingSpaceCategory)
```

Comment: maybe some extensions block it? i.e. adblocker?

Comment: @RieljunLiguid yes man! I think it is caused because the word "Advertisement" is in it. Thank you :)